# Can salt and water be obtained from a reaction between a gas and an acid?

Tags: acid-base

Is it possible to get salt and water (neutralization reaction) by reacting a gas and an acid?

I don't know if it's possible or not. I'm unable to find any examples in this regard.

Would anyone be able to provide an example in support of the question?

Comment: Well, ammonia is a gas.

Comment: I know that ammonia(g) and HCl(aq) produce NH4Cl (s) but I cannot find such a  reaction that  produce salt and water.

Comment: So basically you are looking for a hydroxide that is gaseous...

Comment: Well this will work .Is there any?

Comment: You can vaporize sodium hydroxide into a gas.

Answer (score 1):

English is odd: "a salt" includes $\ce{CaF2}$, $\ce{NH4Cl}$ [as @ortocresol states] and $\ce{NaCl}$ as well as *many* other compounds. Just "salt", though, implies "table salt", $\ce{NaCl}$. So which do you mean?

Any gas that can react with an acid to produce *table salt*, $\ce{NaCl}$ must contain sodium, then. [$\ce{NaOH}$ has a boiling point of 1,661 K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_hydroxide), so bubbling $\ce{NaOH}$ vapor into hydrochloric acid would work. For that matter, [Na boils at 1,156 K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium), so would be easier to do, though it also produces $\ce{H2}$ (as well as water) as a byproduct.

Comment: Fine remark brother.Well, the word salt has nothing to do with table salt; it may be inorganic or organic .In chemistry lab we utter the word salt several times for different purposes.Then your remark  construe that every time we ask for table salt!! I think  it is unimportant to explain what it is;context clearly interprets it.

Comment: Still  if you have any confusion go onto the link please "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(chemistry)".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a salt of $\ce{H3O^+}$ as the acid. Sulfuric acid forms such a solid salt slightly below room temperature, and even when melted at room temperature solutions having the composition corresponding to $\ce{H3O^+HSO4^-}$ retain a strong ionic character (see [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/165288/17175)). Then ammonia may be passed over this hydronium salt to give ammonium sulfate or bisulfate plus water.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get salt, then you should look for a volatile base.
$\ce{NH3}$ does our job here.
$$\ce{2NH3 + H2SO4 -> (NH4)2SO4}$$

However, I am not sure if water could be formed. If there exists something like $\ce{NH4OH}$ vapours, then sure, water will be formed.

Comment: Yeah I also think in this way but I cannot find such reaction to produce salt and water